# Defining the function

Tags: c++, class

```
#include"EAN.h"
 class Order{
 private:
    EAN ean_object;     
    int no_copies;
    int no_delivered;
 public:
    Order();    
    Order(const EAN& ean);
    EAN& getEAN(); 
    int outstanding() const;    
    bool add(std::istream& is); 
    bool add(int n); 
    bool receive(std::istream& is); 
    void display(std::ostream& os) const;
 }; 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Order& order);
```

This is my header file. When i am defining the `EAN& getEAN()` function as `Order::EAN& getEAN()`. Its showing error as no type name `EAN` in `Order` class? How to define it?

Answer (score 4):

> When i am defining the `EAN& getEAN()` function as `Order::EAN& getEAN()`

You have to define it as:

```
EAN& Order::getEAN()
```

In other words, `getEAN()` is a function within the class `Order`. It is erroneous to say `EAN` is a member of the `Order` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
EAN& Order::getEAN() { /* ... */ }
```

instead of

```
Order::EAN& getEAN() { /* ... */ }
```

That is member function getEAN itself indeed is declared in class Order while type EAN is not defined in class Order though it is used in the class Order definition.